# Propagating events from ScrollView to its container in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, touch-event

I'm facing a problem that is making my head explode. Basically I have a FrameLayout that recognizes double taps and that contains a vertical ScrollView. The problem is that when I double tap on the ScrollView, the event is not propagated to the FrameLayout. If the FrameLayout is empty, double tap is recognized correctly.

I already tried subclassing the ScrollView and returning false from the onTouchEvent method: the double tap event is recognized by the FrameLayout but the ScrollView doesn't scroll anymore.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intercept the touch by overriding `ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)` in the `FrameLayout` and return true if the event was handled so it isn't passed down or false if you want the `ScrollView` to handle the event.

Comment: So let me understand this: a touch event is first intercepted by the container and then is propagated to its subviews, not the other way around (from the subviews up to the container) ?

Comment: That is correct.  The event is passed down.  There is a `onDispatchTouchEvent` in `Activity` which will let you handle the event before any view does which can be useful.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm unable to make this work. Maybe I'm missing something but, in onInterceptTouchEvent it would be helpful something like "ev is a double tap? then return true, else false" but I really don't know how to implement something like this. Do you have any suggestions, please? TY

Comment: You could have a look at `GestureDetector` interface and implement it in the custom `FrameLayout` or `Activity`.  It has a specific `OnDoubleTapListener`.

Comment: Thank you Techi, by overriding onInterceptTouch and by doing as you suggested in the last comment I finally made it work!

Comment: Congrats.  Glad I could help.  Also have a read of this http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/.  It will show how to handle the touch events which generally come in three (down, move, up) so you can make your own gesture code.